# Drupal callback page without the leftside menu

Tags: drupal, callback

Im trying to make a drupal commerce module, and need to make a couple of callback pages, that will be echoed from our paymentprovider.

These pages are no problem to make, and they work just fine .. except .. i wish to hide the left side menu block (including shoppingcart and what else might show up there)..
So basicly a blank, but themed page only showing the payment info. (like on the review page).

How do i do this, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Create from your `page.tpl.php` (it's located in your theme folder) next file: `page--ECHOEDPAGENAME.tpl.php` and remove from inside this file regions printing:
For drupal 6 it looks like: `<?php print $sidebar_first; ?>`
For drupal 7 it looks like: `<?php print render($page['sidebar_first']); ?>`
Of course, you also should remove surrounding div that draw sidebars and other regions (footer, right sidebar etc, if required).

Answer (score 0):

Why you can't use visibity settings? If you need to do this in module, i think you need to use hook_page_alter to preprocess render arry of needed page.

Comment: This is almost certainly solved with block visibility settings.